# It is worth to get a bachelor degree in education?

Tags: teaching, job, degree, education

What can I do with a bachelor degree in education and what are the pros and cons of getting a degree in education?

Comment: Pro: you can be an educator. Con: you might prefer to be a firefighter instead.

Comment: You might want to specify which part of the world you are in. For example, we discussed [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107551/79875) that a degree in education will not in itself allow you to teach in the US (though it's a common path towards meeting the requirements); things are different elsewhere. Note also that undergraduate admissions and post-graduate careers are off-topic here (so your question is likely to be closed), though there is probably some way to reword your question so that it fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to teach at any level, even in industry, a degree in education is valuable, and, in many cases, especially at the lower levels, is a requirement. It can also be a gateway to graduate degrees for a person who wants to do educational research, especially in academia. My former spouse, for example, was professor of educational psychology, a common specialty.

In most places in the US, perhaps all, a bachelors is required for a teacher. For elementary education that mostly means a bachelors in education, but there can be exceptions. For higher levels it may be somewhat less of a requirement that your degree be in education specifically, though you probably will need to take courses in education to advance in either elementary or secondary level teaching. Usually, the credits you are required to learn can also be applied to a masters in education.

But note that a degree in education has many possibilities. There are differences in programs that focus on elementary education and secondary education, for example. And some programs, geared toward teaching adults, can be valuable for a person wanting to be a "trainer" in industry.

For university teaching, such qualifications are seldom needed unless you want to teach in an education department. But if you want to teach math, for example, in a university, math degrees are normally needed, not education credits. But a math degree, alone, will probably not qualify you for teaching at the elementary level and may or may not at the secondary level. And, again, someone teaching secondary level math will probably be required to earn several education credits to keep their job, though, perhaps, not to get hired initially.

Whether it is "worth it" or not depends on what you contemplate for your career.